# Error accessing to property in Flex (mxml)

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flex-mx

I have an `MXML` file with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="30">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function initLayer(name:String):void{
                t_layer.text = name;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Grid id="mainGrid" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <mx:GridRow>
            <mx:GridItem width="80%">
                <mx:Text id="t_layer" text="new" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</mx:Canvas>
```

From another AS file, I'm creating a `Layer` object:

```
public function addLayer(name:String):void{
    var layer:Layer = new Layer();
    layer.initLayer(name);
    layer.x = 0;
    layer.y = _layers*layer.height;
    layersContainer.addChild(layer);
    _layers++;
}
```

But I'm getting an error inside `initLayer` function relative to `undefined property for null object t_layer`.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

**EDIT**:

I can't believe it. Just answering Timofei and when I test my ode it works. How? I change order of the functions inside my `addLayer` method like this:

```
public function addLayer(name:String):void{
        var layer:Layer = new Layer();
        layer.x = 0;
        layer.y = _layers*layer.height;
        layersContainer.addChild(layer);
        layer.initLayer(name);
        _layers++;
}
```

Comment: The elusive Heisenbug.  If you find out anything more you can flag again to reopen so you can post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When do you call `initLayer`? Do it not earlier, than `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` is dispatched by your canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm unable to check this event because the function where I created the object is inside another one. I'll edit my question to clarify it.